# How to sign message in python the same way it is signed in Javascript by using the ECDSA secp256k1 curve?

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography, digital-signature, ecdsa

I am trying to sign a byte array in python by the same way as it happens on the crypto library with the [secp256k1 from NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secp256k1)

This is the code on NodeJS/Browser:

```
const secp256k1 = require('secp256k1')

var message = [2, 118, 145, 101, 166, 249, 149, 13, 2, 58, 65, 94, 230, 104, 184, 11, 185, 107, 92, 154, 226, 3, 93, 151, 189, 251, 68, 243, 86, 23, 90, 68, 255, 111, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 187, 226, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 84, 101, 115, 116, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var private_key_buffer = [122, 241, 114, 103, 51, 227, 157, 149, 221, 126, 157, 173, 31, 111, 43, 118, 208, 71, 123, 59, 96, 68, 57, 177, 53, 59, 151, 188, 36, 167, 40, 68]

const signature = secp256k1.sign(SHA3BUF(message), private_key_buffer)
```

This is my implementation in python:

```
import hashlib
import ecdsa

message = bytearray([2, 118, 145, 101, 166, 249, 149, 13, 2, 58, 65, 94, 230, 104, 184, 11, 185, 107, 92, 154, 226, 3, 93, 151, 189, 251, 68, 243, 86, 23, 90, 68, 255, 111, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 187, 226, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 84, 101, 115, 116, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

private_key_buffer = bytearray([122, 241, 114, 103, 51, 227, 157, 149, 221, 126, 157, 173, 31, 111, 43, 118, 208, 71, 123, 59, 96, 68, 57, 177, 53, 59, 151, 188, 36, 167, 40, 68])

signinKey = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key_buffer, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)

signature = signinKey.sign_deterministic(message, hashfunc=hashlib.sha3_256)
```

but by some reason, the signature I get in the javascript code is diferent from the python code:

```
java script signature: [23, 54, 64, 151, 95, 33, 200, 66, 246, 166, 144, 182, 81, 179, 124, 223, 250, 50, 137, 169, 45, 181, 197, 74, 225, 207, 116, 125, 50, 241, 38, 52, 118, 215, 252, 94, 191, 154, 200, 195, 152, 73, 1, 197, 158, 24, 72, 177, 118, 39, 241, 82, 114, 107, 25, 106, 67, 205, 202, 4, 7, 57, 82, 237]

python script signature: [213, 69, 97, 237, 85, 226, 217, 201, 51, 14, 220, 92, 105, 59, 54, 92, 87, 88, 233, 147, 191, 15, 21, 86, 134, 202, 205, 223, 83, 134, 70, 39, 10, 19, 147, 20, 181, 180, 88, 103, 79, 55, 144, 98, 84, 2, 224, 127, 192, 200, 200, 250, 170, 129, 67, 99, 163, 72, 92, 253, 109, 108, 104, 206]
```

So how can I make the python code output the same signature of the JS code?

Comment: What is SHA3BUF here? is it SHA3-256?

Comment: Yes, it is a sha3  hash function

Comment: And yes, a 256 bit one

Comment: Are you sure that SHA3(_256) is used in the NodeJS-code? Older implementations sometimes use Keccak(_256), [here](https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/are-you-really-using-sha-3-or-old-code-c5df31ad2b0). This is often confused. [Here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html) both hashs can be compared online. The signatures of the [test vectors](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=285142.40) for secp256k1 and SHA256 (there are none for SHA3_256) can be reproduced. Thus, both libraries seem to implement [RFC6979](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6979) according to the documentation.

Comment: @Topaco hey, yes.. NodeJS implementation is using it because I did hash the message array in python using the sha3_256 with hash lib and when compared with  SHA3BUF(message) function result it gave me the same arrays.. This is the script that I am trying to port to python: http://dappsgate.com/_test-api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the *deterministic* ECDSA as described in [RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979), a hash algorithm is used in two places: One algorithm (`H1`) is used for hashing the message, another (`H2`) for determining the `k`-value. `k` is a parameter within the signature algorithm, whose role is described e.g. in [RFC6979, section 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979#section-2.4) or also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm). For the non-deterministic variant `k` is determined randomly, for the deterministic variant as described in RFC6979.

RFC6979 doesn't specify that `H1` and `H2` must be different, see [RFC6979, section 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979#section-3.6). Nevertheless, it makes sense that an implementation offers the possibility to define both hash algorithms separately.

1. The ECDSA implementation of Python *generally* allows two different hash algorithms to be applied. Before this is shown in the 2nd case, the following variant, which correponds to the posted Python-code, applies the *same* hash algorithm `H1 = H2 = SHA3-256`. The hash algorithm specified in the `sign_deterministic`-method defines both `H1` and `H2`:

   ```
    import hashlib
    import ecdsa

    message = b'Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.'
    private_key_buffer = bytearray.fromhex('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001') 

    sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key_buffer, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1) 
    signature = sk.sign_deterministic(message, hashfunc=hashlib.sha3_256)

    print(signature.hex())
   ```

   The signature is:

   ```
    r = 88ecdbc6a2762e7ad1160f7c984cd61385ff07982280538dd7d2103be2dce720
    s = c1487df9feab7afda6e6115bdd4d9c5316e3f917a3235a5e47aee09624491304
   ```
2. The next variant uses `H1 = SHA3-256` for hashing the message and `H2 = SHA256` for `k`-determination. This is possible by replacing the `sign_deterministic`-method with the `sign_digest_deterministic`-method, which allows separate hashing of the message with `H1`. The hash algorithm specified in the `sign_digest_deterministic`-method then only defines `H2`:

   ```
    import hashlib
    import ecdsa

    message = b'Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.'
    private_key_buffer = bytearray.fromhex('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001') 

    digest = hashlib.sha3_256()
    digest.update(message)
    hash = digest.digest()

    sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key_buffer, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1) 
    signature = sk.sign_digest_deterministic(hash, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)

    print(signature.hex())
   ```

   The signature is:

   ```
    r = 64b10395957b78d3bd3db279e5fa4ebee36b58dd1becace4bc2d7e3a04cf6259
    s = 19f1eee7495064ac679d7b64ab7213b921b650c0a3746f2938ffeede0ff1f2e8
   ```
3. The following code is functionally identical to the posted NodeJS-code:

   ```
    const secp256k1 = require('secp256k1')
    const sha3 = require('js-sha3')

    message = 'Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.'
    private_key_buffer = Buffer.from('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001','hex')

    digest = sha3.sha3_256;
    hash = Buffer.from(digest(message), 'hex')

    signature = secp256k1.sign(hash, private_key_buffer)
    console.log(signature.signature.toString('hex'))
   ```

   and generates the *same* signature as in the 2nd case, i.e. apparently `H2 = SHA256`. I didn't find a way to change this to `SHA3-256` without much effort. However, according to the documentation it is possible to [replace the default generator](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node/blob/master/API.md#signbuffer-message-buffer-privatekey--object-options---signature-buffer-recovery-number) that implements RFC6979. This should also change `H2`, but could be more expensive.

*In summary:* The simplest way to fix the incompatibility of both codes
is to change the Python-code as described above in the 2nd case, i.e. to use the `sign_digest_deterministic`-method. The message is then hashed with `SHA3-256`, the `k`-generation takes place with `SHA256`. A more expensive alternative would be to implement an own generator to enable `k`-generation with `SHA3-256` in the NodeJS-code. Or of course, you try to find another ECDSA-library for the NodeJS-code that allows you to define `H1` and `H2` separately, analogous to the Python-code.

**Update:**

*Canonical signature*: If `(r,s)` is a signature, then `(r, -s mod n) = (r, n - s)` is also a [*valid* signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm). Here [`n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm) is the order of the base point. If in case `s > n/2` the part `-s mod n = n - s` is used instead of `s`, then the result for the signature is *unambiguous* and is limited to the area below `n/2`. This is called *canonical signature*, which is particularly relevant for the [Bitcoin topic](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#low-s-values-in-signatures) and also frequently used for [test vectors](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=285142.msg3300992#msg3300992).

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to work.. The "sign_digest_deterministic" was the key that I was looking for. Thanks for this awesome explanation!

Comment: At first I tought the signatures were equal but by some reason, only r values from both implementations are equals.. s values are diferent.. could this be a bug of one of the implementations ?

Comment: No, it's probably not a bug. I assume that the signature is in one case `(r,s)`, in the other case `(r, -s mod n)`. Try the _canonical representation_, which uniquely maps the `s`-value to the area below `n/2`. For more details see the update-section in my answer. If this doesn't solve the problem, post the two signatures and everything needed for a repro.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! looking into the ecdsa lib I saw that `sigencode_string_canonize` does exactly what you explained. Here is how I did get the points I needed: `sk.sign_digest_deterministic(hash, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256, sigencode=sigencode_string_canonize)`